# IBM.Data.DB.Provider Nuget Package

Tags: db2, nuget-package, ibm-data-db2

I am using [IBM.Data.DB.Provider Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB.Provider/) but I receive licensing error. as per [License Details](http://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?li_formnum=L-JERN-AVZQZZ&title=IBM%20Data%20Server%20Driver%20for%20ADO.NET%20v11.1) I simply have to copy a license file in the license folder of this Nuget Package. I wanted to know if I can acquire a Trail license for it to present my 'Proof of Concept' to our team. Once approved, our management will acquire a license from IBM.

**Furthermore, I wanted to clarify that this Nuget Package (after fixing license issues) will not require any installation at all on our web farm because that's not permitted by our infrastructure team.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago. A DB2 trial licence can be obtained for 90 days from [IBM's website](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/db2/trials/). I found the customer support very helpful. You can contact support using the yellow "Lets Talk" button in the bottom right.

Comment: I reached out to the owner of the Nuget package and the responded back in a prompt and positive way to share the evaluation license :)